# ERROR: column "field" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration

I've hit an SQL problem that I'm a bit mystified by. I have two different
questions regarding this problem:

- Why?
- How do I work around it?

The following query:

```
SELECT subs.date_added,subs.subscribed_to,users.userid, users.username, users.email, users.avatar, users.fbuid, users.level, users.avatar_url, users.sex, users.dob, users.profile_hits, users.total_videos, users.subscribers, users.doj, users.extras, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.ban_status, users.usr_status, users.last_logged, users.country, users.user_filter_level, users.signup_ip, subs.userid as subscriber 
FROM cb_subscriptions as subs 
     LEFT JOIN cb_users AS users 
     ON subs.userid=users.userid 
WHERE subs.subscribed_to ='2960' 
GROUP BY subs.subscribed_to ,subs.userid 
ORDER BY subs.date_added ASC 
LIMIT 8;
```

...produces the following error:

```
ERROR: column "users.userid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

That field is a `CHAR`, so I'm not sure what kind of aggregate to use,
or (more important to my understanding) why one is necessary.

As I said, I'm not sure I understand why this occurs.  I'm assuming that I
don't understand `group by` as well as I thought I did ;)

This isn't my query, I'm translating a system prototyped in MySQL to
PostgreSQL.  This query *does* work in MySql.  Does that constitute a
bug in MySql, or a shortcoming of PostgreSQL, or just a difference of
interpretation?

And when I added this column in the `group by` clause it's working, but I don't understand why?

#### Working query

```
SELECT subs.date_added, users.userid, users.username, users.email, 
       users.avatar, users.fbuid, users.level, users.avatar_url, 
       users.sex, users.dob, users.profile_hits, users.total_videos,
       users.subscribers, users.doj, users.extras, users.first_name, 
       users.last_name, users.ban_status, users.usr_status, 
       users.last_logged, users.country, users.user_filter_level, 
       users.signup_ip, subs.userid as subscriber 
FROM cb_subscriptions as subs 
     LEFT JOIN cb_users AS users 
     ON subs.userid=users.userid 
WHERE subs.subscribed_to ='2960' 
GROUP BY users.userid, 
         subs.subscribed_to, 
         subs.userid, 
         subs.date_added 
ORDER BY subs.date_added ASC 
LIMIT 8;
```

#### cb_subscriptions DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_subscriptions` (
    `subscription_id` int(225) NOT NULL,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `subscribed_to` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `cb_subscriptions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`subscription_id`);

ALTER TABLE `cb_subscriptions`
  MODIFY `subscription_id` int(225) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

#### cb_users DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_users` (
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fbuid` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_session_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_session_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usr_status` enum('Ok','ToActivate') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ToActivate',
  `msg_notify` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  `avatar` varchar(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `avatar_url` text NOT NULL,
  `sex` enum('male','female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'male',
  `dob` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PK',
  `level` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `avcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `doj` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_logged` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `num_visits` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `signup_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time_zone` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `featured_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `profile_hits` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `total_watched` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_videos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_comments` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_photos` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_collections` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `comments_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_commented` datetime NOT NULL,
  `voted` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL,
  `likes_count` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `ban_status` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `upload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `subscribers` bigint(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_subscriptions` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `background` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `background_color` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `background_url` text NOT NULL,
  `background_repeat` enum('no-repeat','repeat','repeat-x','repeat-y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'repeat',
  `background_attachement` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `total_groups` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `banned_users` text NOT NULL,
  `welcome_email_sent` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `total_downloads` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_subscribed` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `album_privacy` enum('public','private','friends') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'private',
  `extras` text NOT NULL,
  `user_filter_level` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `cb_users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  ADD KEY `ind_status_doj` (`doj`),
  ADD KEY `ind_status_id` (`userid`),
  ADD KEY `ind_hits_doj` (`profile_hits`,`doj`),
  ADD KEY `username` (`username`);
```

Comment: You seem to be selecting both subs.user_id and users.user_id - but you're joining on this field, you should only need to select one of them

Comment: That is because in earlier versions of Mysql < 8 [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) was disabled by default, If you want to test enable this mode or run your queries on 8+ you will get the same error

Comment: "Does that constitute a bug in MySql, or a shortcoming of PostgreSQL, or just a difference of interpretation?" That's somewhat open to opinion: access to *all* non-grouped columns is a non-standard feature of MySQL, which some would consider a useful feature (and therefore "missing" from Postgres), but others would consider problematic (and therefore "wrong" in MySQL); apparently, even MySQL no longer enables it by default. On the other hand, access to "functionally dependent" columns is considered a "correct" feature, but hard to implement fully.

Comment: Fixed @ https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209371/error-column-field-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggreg

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem @ databases stack exchange please check there for more details
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209371/error-column-field-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggreg